# Cannot convert multi-layer SpatRaster from numeric to categorical

Tags: r, terra

I have problems to convert multi-layer SpatRaster objects to categorical.
No problem to convert a 1-layer spatraster:

```
r <-  rast(RStoolbox::rlogo)
k <- kmeans(r,4)
c <- r[[1]]
values(c) <- k$cluster
c <- as.factor(c)
> c
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 77, 101, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
source(s)   : memory
categories  : label 
name        : label 
min value   :     1 
max value   :     4
```

If I try:

```
ggplot() +
geom_spatraster(data = c)+ 
scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

but this works out

```
values(c) <- as.factor(values(c))
ggplot() +
      geom_spatraster(data = c)+ 
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

But I have a sequence of classifications, such as c below:

```
> r <-  rast(RStoolbox::rlogo)
> c <- r
> k1 <- kmeans(r,4)
> k2 <- kmeans(r,2)
> k3 <- kmeans(r,5)
> values(c[[1]]) <- as.factor(k1$cluster)
> values(c[[2]]) <- as.factor(k2$cluster)
> values(c[[3]]) <- as.factor(k3$cluster)
> values(c[[1]]) <- k1$cluster
> values(c[[2]]) <- k2$cluster
> values(c[[3]]) <- k3$cluster
> c
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 77, 101, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
source(s)   : memory
names       : red, green, blue 
min values  :   1,     1,    1 
max values  :   4,     2,    5
```

And have to convert to factor:

```
> c <- as.factor(c)
> ggplot() +
+   geom_spatraster(data = c[[1]])+ 
+   scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
#or
values(c) <- values(as.factor(c))
ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster(data = c[[1]])+ 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

How can I convert all layers to factor?

Answer (score 2):

Example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))
crs(r) <- "+proj=utm +zone=1"   
km <- kmeans(r,4)
k <- setValues(r[[1]], km$cluster)
x <- c(k, k, k)
```

The simplest way to create factors is to do

```
xf <- as.factor(x)
is.factor(xf)
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

And now you can do

```
library(tidyterra)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_spatraster(data = x[[1]]) + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

[image]

Other ways to create factors:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=1:4, label=paste0("k_", 1:4))
levels(k) <- df

dlst <- replicate(nlyr(x), df, simplify = FALSE)
levels(x) <- dlst
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 77, 101, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source(s)   : memory
#names       : label, label, label 
#min values  :   k_1,   k_1,   k_1 
#max values  :   k_4,   k_4,   k_4
```

Comment: It was just a matter of upgrading. My code works as yours with terra 1.7.21